# Why does chrome dev tools console show a link for Post 500 error in one website but not another?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, iis

In test1 web site I can get debugging information with a Post link
[image: test1]

In test2 web site, running the same api, I cannot.
I just see

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500()

[image: test2]

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, should this question have an IIS tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In web.config

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Auto" />
```

[The docs are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/)